# Amazon EFS access denied while mounting in docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-container, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount an EFS file system on a Docker container on a EC2 server.
The problem is that I can successfully mount the file system on the EC2 host system, but not in the container, I get the following error in the container :
`mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting`

The container is launched with the following command :
`docker run -it --name efs-image  --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_OVERRIDE --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH --restart always --net host --pid host --env-file env.env debian`

I could mount the file system on the host then share it in a volume with the container, but I would like to mount it on the container for scaling reasons.

I tried to restart the docker doemon with `service docker restart`, but I still have the same error.

Can someone explain how to mount the EFS in the container ?

Thanks in advance !